# Data Lodad with fetch-Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: reactjs

> When I am trying to load local data.It causes errors.But when I am
> trying to load API data it works as my expectation.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useFoods = () => {
    const [foods,setFoods]=useState([])
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('breakfast.json')
          .then(res=>res.json())
          .then(data=>setFoods(data))
    },[])
    //console.log(foods)
    return [foods]
};

export default useFoods;
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you put your `breakfast.json` file inside the public directory. that's where react will look for this file.

Comment: I have put the file inside the public directory

Comment: I tested your exact code on my machine and it works fine. I can't think of anything else than locating your file correctly and making sure it's valid json.

Comment: It is working fine now.But haven't identified what was happened

Comment: That's the beauty of programming :)